# On a regular surface, curves are locally cut out by one function

Tags: algebraic-geometry, surfaces

Let $S$ be a regular surface over a field $k$ and $C$ an irreducible curve on it. if $p \in C$ is a (closed) point, then I know that $C$ is cut out locally (in $\mathcal O_{S,p}$) by one function.

The proof (sketch) I came up with uses some heavy tools, namely that $\mathcal O_{S,p}$ is a regular local ring and hence factorial. Then, if $f \in \mathcal O_{S,p}$ is such that $V(f) \supset C$, we can find a factor $g|f$ such that $V(g) = C$.

This is because $V(f)$ is a union of irreducible curves and since $C$ is irreducible, one of these curves has to in fact be $C$. On the other hand, since $\mathcal O_{S,p}$ is a UFD, irreducible elements correspond to prime ideals and we are done.

Is there a simpler proof of this fact?

Edit: Ideally, I would like to completely avoid the result "regular local ring $\implies$ UFD" but this might be too much to ask for. However, perhaps there is an easier proof of this result in the case of surfaces (local ring is dimension 2)? There is a reasonable easy proof in the case of dimension one at least...

Comment: You meant $\mathcal O_{S,p}$ rather than $\mathcal O_{C,p}$ -- otherwise it's essentially the right idea. A litlle more direct is to use the fact that in a Noetherian UFD height-$1$ primes are principal.

Comment: That is an embarassing typo... Anyway, I would like to avoid the hard result (regular local rings are UFD) or at least, see an easier proof of this statement for the case of a surface (2 dimensional rings).

Comment: I don't think that you can avoid that. It is not that hard though.

Comment: I was just curious because this result seems to have been known to the ancients (pre 1900), do you know if they had some sort of a rigorous proof?

Comment: @Asvin As far as I can tell, the first proof that two-dimensional regular local rings are UFD's still uses Auslander–Buchsbaum–Serre's homological characterization of regular local rings; see Theorem 2.14 in [Auslander–Buchsbaum 1957](https://doi.org/10.1090/S0002-9947-1957-0086822-7).